# ActionBar is not showing the progress bar

Tags: android, webview, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-actionbaractivity

I have the WebView and I want to while page is loading in the WebView, in ActionBar show progress. The application is using AppCompat Android library and the app's target and compile SDK version is 21. Just the WebView running normally.

I think problem in the method `setSupportProgress(int progress)`.

My code is the below.

Activity:

```
public class AuthActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private boolean isConfirmationRequired = false;
private Utils utils = new Utils();

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth);

    final String authUrl = "some url";
    final WebView authWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.auth_web_view);
    authWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    authWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            setTitle(R.string.loading);
            setSupportProgress(newProgress * 100);

            if (newProgress == 100)
                setTitle(R.string.sign_in);
        }
    });

    authWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            if (!url.equals(authUrl))
                isConfirmationRequired = true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
            boolean hasUserBrokenAuth = url.equals("some url") ||
                    url.equals("some url");
            boolean isUserAuthorized = url.startsWith("some url" +
                    "access_token=");

            if (hasUserBrokenAuth) {
                if (isConfirmationRequired)
                    utils.showConfirmDialog(AuthActivity.this);
                else
                    finish();
            } else {
                utils.webViewLoadUrlIfInternetIsConnected(AuthActivity.this, authWebView, url);
                if (isUserAuthorized)
                    saveAuthData(url);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    utils.webViewLoadUrlIfInternetIsConnected(this, authWebView, authUrl);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if (isConfirmationRequired) {
            utils.showConfirmDialog(this);
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    if (isConfirmationRequired) {
        utils.showConfirmDialog(this);
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

private void saveAuthData(String url) {
    String accessToken = utils.extractPattern(url, "access_token=(.*?)&");
    String userId = utils.extractPattern(url, "user_id=(\\d*)");
}
```

utils.webViewLoadUrlIfInternetIsConnected:

```
public void webViewLoadUrlIfInternetIsConnected(final Context context, final WebView webView,
                                                final String url) {
    if (isInternetConnected(context)) {
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    } else {
        showSnackbarInternetDisconnected(context, new ActionClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onActionClicked(Snackbar snackbar) {
                snackbar.dismiss();
                webViewLoadUrlIfInternetIsConnected(context, webView, url);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AppCompat does not support showing a progress view as it was possible, so you can remove following from your code:

```
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(...);
```

There is the possibility to use the new toolbar instead, I tried it by myself today, but it complicates all. The solution I ended with was to set a menu item more that references a layout which references a drawbale:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_progress"
    android:visible="false"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/progress_indeterminate"
    tools:ignore="AlwaysShowAction,UnusedAttribute"/>
```

Then the layout looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_wheel" />
```

And the drawable as follow (you can customize this as you want):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="720" >

<shape
    android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="12"
    android:useLevel="false" >

    <gradient
        android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:centerY="0.50"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:startColor="#000000"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false" />
</shape>
</rotate>
```

Then in onCreateOptionsMenu you initialize the menuItem with following:

```
mProgressMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_progress);
```

and with setVisibility you can chage the visibility of the menu anywhere in your activity.

Comment: A great solution, thanks.  Just instead of the custom drawable, I added style="?android:attr/android:progressBarStyleSmall"  to the ProgressBar layout.

Comment: I know, but I explicitly used the custom drawable to have the same one on each Android version.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to update the `Visibility` of `ProgressBar` with [setSupportProgressBarVisibility(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#setSupportProgressBarVisibility(boolean)) as follows:

```
// set Visibility to TRUE
setSupportProgressBarVisibility(true);
```

And then, in `onProgressChanged`, disable its `Visibility` when the progress ends:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
    setTitle(R.string.loading);
    setSupportProgress(newProgress * 100);

    if (newProgress == 100) {
        // set it to FALSE
        setSupportProgressBarVisibility(false);
        setTitle(R.string.sign_in);
    }
    //...
}
```

---

***Update:***

Another solution might be to use a custom `Progress View` added to the `AppCompat`.

You have to **inflate** the custom view which contains a horizontal ProgressBar, **get** the ActionBar **container** ViewGroup and **add the custom view** to the container:

```
/** Inflate a custom view **/
View ab_progressView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ab_progressbar, null)
/** Get the ActionBar container **/
ViewGroup ab_container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_container);
/** Add the custom view **/
ab_container.addView(ab_progressView);
```

> If `ab_container` returns a `NullPointerException`, you just have to create a new `Runnable` to get its id in a parallel thread.

You have to set this new view at the bottom of ActionBar:

```
/** Create layout parameters **/
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
     LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
/** Set the gravity **/
params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
/** Set these params to your view **/
ab_progressView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Then update the progress:

```
/** Get the progress bar **/
final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) ab_progressView.findViewById(R.id.progress);

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
    /** Update the progress **/
    progressBar.setProgress(newProgress * 100);
}
```

When, the progress ends, just remove the custom view:

```
/** Remove the custom view added **/
ab_container.removeView(ab_progressView);
```

I didn't test this solution, but it should work..

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help me. Are there any other solutions?